# How do I reveal a div in my Rails template using CoffeeScript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have the following code in my index page.

```
<button id= 'form-show' class= 'btn btn-primary form-btn'> Add Transaction</button
<div class='row'>
  <%=render 'form'%>
</div>
```

And the following CoffeeScript:

```
$('#form-show').click ->
  $('#form-section').slideDown()
```

The button is supposed to reveal a form partial that's already loaded in the DOM but hidden through:

```
#form-section{
  display: none;
}
```

However when I click this button nothing happens. The form doesn't show up. I don't know what could be wrong. It's such a simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

`Add Transaction</button`

Something is missing... Look again... A closing `>`...

Answer (score 0):

I've created a snippet. I've converted CoffeeScript to javascript as the editor doesn't support it here. Everything seems to work.

So I think the following reasons could be the issue.

- The rendered form from rails doesn't have the same id i.e, `form-section`
- Your javascript is loaded without a `document` on `ready` function. So make sure your code is wrapped inside `$(document).ready` function like this:

  `$(document).ready(->
    $('#form-show').click(->
      $("#form-section").slideDown()
    )
  )`
- Your jquery is not defined properly. Check for any console errors you're getting. And post it here.

```js
$('#form-show').click(function(){
  $('#form-section').slideDown()
})
```

```css
#form-section{
  display: none;
  background: #de9a44;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='form-show' class= 'btn btn-primary form-btn'> Add Transaction</button
<div class='row'>
  <form id="form-section">
    <h3>Form</h3>
    <input type="text" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, i found the problem  i didnt add a $ -> on in my coffee-script command. i believe the the document ready. such. such a ridiculous error. will give more fuller code references.

Comment: Cool. Let me know what if that works out or you are still facing any issue.